# Add directory to system path in OS X Lion

Tags: shell, path, playframework, osx-lion, playframework-2.0

I can't figure out how to add a directory to the system path. I found out that the command is something like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/my_path/to/my_dir
```

### Example

I run the terminal in the path where my installation directory is located. In this case I'm talking about Play Framework. And I type:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/to/play20
```

It looks like nothing happens. In fact, when I type the command "play" (to execute the framework) I get:

```
-bash: play: command not found
```

Can someone please give me a decent step-by-step guide?

Comment: Is the program in `/to/play20` or in `/to/play20/bin`?  Is it a Mac OS X application (`.app` directory)?

Comment: The executable is in play20 and it is not a Os X app. Here's the guide I follow http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/Installing

Comment: did you this command before : `chmod +x /path/to/play20/play` ?

Comment: yes. But the command I used is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Execute the command “/to/play20/play help”. If this gives the expected output (help for the play command), then the executable is available, and the problem is in the shell path. If it does not give the expected output, then the executable is not working.

In the former case, ensure you are running the bash shell. (This is the default for recent versions of Mac OS X, but it may be changed for specific accounts.) To do this temporarily, execute the command “bash”. (When you want to exit the temporary shell, execute the command “exit”.) Then execute the export command again. (When the export command works, it changes the variable without displaying any output, so this is normal.) Check the spelling in the export command carefully.

In the latter case, execute “ls -ld /to/play20/play”. If you get a message that the file does not exist, then the executable is not installed correctly, and I cannot help you further. If the file is present, then it is not executable for some reason. This might be because you do not have permission to access it (especially permission to execute it, marked by “x” in certain places in the initial field of the ls output that may contain hyphens, “r”, “w”, and a few other letters) or that it is a symbolic link to a file that does not exist (indicated by an “l” in the first character of the ls output for the file). Lack of permission can be fixed by the chmod command, assuming you have appropriate permissions for changing permissions on the system. If the file is a symbolic link to another file, you may have a bad installation, or the target file may have permission issues (or be another symbolic link, and so on).

Comment: If I type this ./play20/play help it works. So I type "bash" in the shell. I add permission to play then I type "export PATH=$PATH:/play20". Finally I type "play" in the terminal and I get "command not found". Uff.. This is really annoying. I did all what you said: the file exist and has permission. I think I do something wrong with the path things.

Comment: There's a HUGE difference between `./play20/play` and `/play20/play` (except when the current directory is the root directory, `/`).  The first means a relative pathname to the current directory; to add that to $PATH, do `export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/play20`.  The second doesn't work, as you've demonstrated.  It looks like you haven't yet installed the software; it is just compiled up and you are still working in the build area.

Comment: Well the software it has not to be installed. You just download a directory with an executable and that's all. I just want to add this exe to my working path. It works using "export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/play20" as you said. But every time I close the shell I need to retype the export command in order to get the "play" command. How can I make it permanent?

Comment: @JohnEntropy: Why would you ask about “/to/play20” in your question but actually use “./play20” in your attempt? Clearly they are different. You must accurately describe and report the exact events before you can expect help.

Comment: @JohnEntropy: The PATH variable is set when the shell starts. The export command changes it only in the current shell instance; it does not change the value PATH is set to when the shell starts. A common way to set the value of PATH in a durable way is to put an export command in the file ~/.bash_profile. (“~” stands for your home directory.) When bash starts as a login shell, if ~/.bash_profile exists and is executable, bash executes the commands in it. (This is for a single user. There are other methods for system-wide effects.)